# AWS - Can't create second mirroring session for one target

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm configuring traffic mirroring in one VPC. I need to send traffic from few instances on one target.

I created one session but when I'm trying to create second session I have error "An unknown error occurred".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

For mirroring you can use only EC2 instance that is powered by the AWS Nitro system (A1, C5, C5d, C5n, I3en, M5, M5a, M5ad, M5d, p3dn.24xlarge, R5, R5a, R5ad, R5d, T3, T3a, and z1d)